# In shell script is it possible to Grade out or Blur specific line?

Tags: shell

In shell is it possible to Grade out or Blur specific line .
(Example. :  Hide Username/Password  content in certain Shell -Security specific reason.  ) 
or I want to  Hide out the line or specific content /command Is it Possible?  If yes. , Could you Possible help out.

Answer (score 0):

This one is bash compatible :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #set -x

    typeset -A COLOR

    ## Reset to normal: \033[0m
    COLOR[NORM]="\033[0m"

    ## Colors:
    COLOR[BLACK]="\033[0;30m"
    COLOR[GRAY]="\033[1;30m"
    COLOR[RED]="\033[0;31m"
    COLOR[LRED]="\033[1;31m"
    COLOR[GREEN]="\033[0;32m"
    COLOR[LGREEN]="\033[1;32m"
    COLOR[YELLOW]="\033[0;33m"
    COLOR[LYELLOW]="\033[1;33m"
    COLOR[BLUE]="\033[0;34m"
    COLOR[LBLUE]="\033[1;34m"
    COLOR[PURPLE]="\033[0;35m"
    COLOR[PINK]="\033[1;35m"
    COLOR[CYAN]="\033[0;36m"
    COLOR[LCYAN]="\033[1;36m"
    COLOR[LGRAY]="\033[0;37m"
    COLOR[WHITE]="\033[1;37m"

    ## Backgrounds
    COLOR[BLACKB]="\033[0;40m"
    COLOR[REDB]="\033[0;41m"
    COLOR[GREENB]="\033[0;42m"
    COLOR[YELLOWB]="\033[0;43m"
    COLOR[BLUEB]="\033[0;44m"
    COLOR[PURPLEB]="\033[0;45m"
    COLOR[CYANB]="\033[0;46m"
    COLOR[GREYB]="\033[0;47m"

    ## Attributes:
    COLOR[UNDERLINE]="\033[4m"
    COLOR[BOLD]="\033[1m"
    COLOR[INVERT]="\033[7m"
    COLOR[BLINK]="\033[5m"

    ## Cursor movements
    CUR_UP="\033[1A"
    CUR_DN="\033[1B"
    CUR_LEFT="\033[1D"
    CUR_RIGHT="\033[1C"

    ## Start of display (top left)
    SOD="\033[1;1f"

    clear
    printf "Colors\n"
    for i in ${!COLOR[@]}; do
            printf $i" = ${COLOR[$i]}The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ${COLOR[NORM]}\n"
    done
```

Normally, you can "mix" attributes (like underline) and color.

Some attributes/colors might or might not work depending on you terminal though.

Hope it helps

Comment: For below code snip if I have to grade or hide out variable declaration area or specific line . What should be approach.
B="$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")"  
#END = "2018-08-16 20:30:00"
C="$(date +%s)"
echo "${C}"   #  epoc
echo "${A}"
echo "${B}"

END="Aug 31 23:59:59"

Comment: The idea is to print the color code, the line and the code for "NORM" to return to the normal. That's what the loop does at the end. I've put the color code in an array for ease, but any variable will do. The best is to run my code, choose a color and use it. On my screen, using Black will obfuscate the print.

Comment: My requirement is to hide certain section of code for example Username/Password or declaration of variable etc in .sh file https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/hiding-password-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Well, sorry didn't understand that in your question...but the answers in your link pretty much answers it then, don't they ?